# CoreData error with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, core-data, iphonecoredatarecipes

When I turn on the Concurrency debug switch 'com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1' to track all concurrency issues with CoreData, I keep getting a crash when calling insertingNewObjectForEntityForName.

The message Xcode shows me is EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0). Here's my code

Here's my implementation of managedObjectContext

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

and here's the implementation of [self privateContext]

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)privateContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *pvtContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
pvtContext.parentContext = [CoreDataMgr sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;
return pvtContext;
}
```

Scenario 1: executing on main thread - does not crash

```
NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [CoreDataMgr sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;
CDPayments* cdPayment = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:PAYMENTS_TABLE inManagedObjectContext:mainContext];
```

Scenario 2: Executing on background thread - CRASHES !!

```
NSManagedObjectContext *pvtContext = [self privateContext];
CDPayments* cdPayment = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:PAYMENTS_TABLE pvtContext];
```

I'm really not clear why executing this on the background thread with a private context is crashing ...

I am using Xcode 8 against iOS9 SDK and the above code is called when saving a payment object.

Comment: Just to debug, have you tried saving this payment in main thread, although UI might hang up but will see it is not the threading problem (like accessing a UI element after saving to core data from background thread) and there is something wrong with the core data mechanism.

Comment: @NeverHopeless, thanks I corrected a mistake I had. It works on the main thread but not when executed on background thread. I've edited my post and added more detail

Comment: Perhaps, go through this may shed some light on the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093595/saving-nsmanagedobjectcontext-with-nsprivatequeueconcurrencytype.

Comment: Can you upload the ASM code and stack trace to check what is wrong.

Comment: @IphoneDeveloper What was the issue?

Answer (score 14):

It's because you're doing Core Data concurrency wrong. When you use `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` or `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`, you **must** wrap your Core Data code in calls to `perform()` or `performAndWait()`. If you don't, your code is violating concurrency rules and this crash is completely expected.

The only exception to this is if you use `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` and you are **certain** that the code is running on the main queue, you can make the Core Data calls directly, without wrapping them in blocks.

Comment: No, its only once you have access to a context you need to wrap your calls in perform() or performAndWait(). If you see my example, I'm trying to insert  a new object for which you just need to mention the context. There's no wrapping with perform in there.

Comment: Any time you "mention" the context, you are using the context. Any time you use the context, you must use those calls. When you "mention" the context, it's not just going along for the ride, it's getting used at some point.

Comment: @TomHarrington Does what you said really hold true? Wouldn't this mean it's impossible to interact with coredata without encapsulating the call in a perform block?

Comment: @Minimi aside from the exception I mentioned, yes, that's what it means.

Comment: Adding performAndWait() using my context solves the problem.