# What does this Error in SwiftUI Core Data WatchOS mean?

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, core-data, watchos

i have an iOS App which deals with Core Data.
Now I want to create a watchOS App which has some of the iOS Views.

My Goal is to let the user create a CoreData Object on the Watch.

If I select in the Target Membership of the CoreData File the watch extension and create a FetchRequest for my Objects everything works fine until I open that view.
If I open the view I get the following error code:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

I have read that there is some kind of solution for UserDefaults but I haven't found anything for CoreData.

Does anyone know how to fix this and how to fetch the Core Data properly?

Edit:
CoreData File: Generated via XCode12

```
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer
    
    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Fitness")
        
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Fetch Request in Watch Extension

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext

@FetchRequest(
        entity: Item.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.name, ascending: false)]
    ) var Itemlist: FetchedResults<Item>
```

I shared all relevant files with the watch extension.

Comment: Please add more details about how you access the context of CoreData, seems similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500684/coredata-error-with-exc-bad-instruction-code-exc-i386-invop-subcode-0x0

Comment: I edited the question